# DOCX does not support more than 63 columns in a table?

Tags: java, ms-word, jasper-reports, export-to-word

We are using Jasper Report 6.1.0 or 5.6.0 jar but not able to find any answer over it

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(sourceFileName, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
System.out.println("started bossssssssssssssssss");
JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
File exportReportFile = new File("/home/ist-140/filename.docx");
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(exportReportFile));
    // exporter.setParameter(JRDocxExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.exportReport();
```

The error is:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: The DOCX format does not support more than 63 columns in a table
```

For the 63 columns in a table limit, which of the following are true:

- its a limitation in the file format / spec
- its a limitation in some/all versions of Word
- its a Jasper limitation

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your quick response ! Actually while generating Doc file using above code I always face the same issue as mentioned into subject. I am not able to find any ans over it. Please help to debug the same.

Answer (score 2):

This *JasperReports* engine performs check during export with help of *JRDocxExporter*. In case having more than ***63*** columns it raises exception.

As you can see this code performs check at ***exportGrid*** method of *JRDocxExporter* class:

```
protected void exportGrid(JRGridLayout gridLayout, JRPrintElementIndex frameIndex) throws JRException {
    CutsInfo xCuts = gridLayout.getXCuts();
    Grid grid = gridLayout.getGrid();
    DocxTableHelper tableHelper = null;

    int rowCount = grid.getRowCount();
    if (rowCount > 0 && grid.getColumnCount() > 63)     {
        throw new JRException(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_KEY_COLUMN_COUNT_OUT_OF_RANGE,  
                new Object[]{grid.getColumnCount()} 
                ); 
    }
```

This is a snippet of implementation at *JR 6.3.0*.

---

#### More info

1. The root of this implementation is a limitation of *MS Word*.
   Some info about this limitation can be found here: [Table column limit and how this is calculated](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ceaf5043-5694-4641-a7e0-cbcca7ac63ce/table-column-limit-and-how-this-is-calculated?forum=worddev)
2. The explanation of problem by *Teodor Danciu* can be found [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531205/exceptions-when-saving-report-docx-format)
3. The source code of current version of *JRDocxExporter* class is [here](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/JRDocxExporter.java)

Answer (score 1):

> When exporting to DOCX, a grid is generated, with each print element being placed into a cell. So, when there are too many elements not aligned, the number of columns can be greater than the docx specs limit.

A partial workaround is to design the report thinking in a grid (like spreadsheet). See:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531205/exceptions-when-saving-report-docx-format

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Word does have an upper limit to the number of columns for a table. The reason is quite practical: There is an upper limit to the page/paper size. A table with more columns is simply not readable.

This restriction applies to all versions of Word. In very early versions even fewer columns were possible.

Answer (score 0):

Its a limitation in some/all versions of Word (i'd say it is a limitation in all versions)
Since MS Word has this limitation, Jasper (actually the JasperReports docx exporter) has this limitation. Otherwise, it would write the 64th and next columns inside the 63rd column.

Open excel, write 65 cells, copy them and paste them in word, add some borders and look how the 63rd cell/colum has the 63rd, 64th and 65th content.

Answer (score 0):

Word tables are indeed limited to 63 columns. If you need more, insert an Excel worksheet and use that, bearing in mind that an embedded worksheet cannot span a page break; otherwise, you could link to an external Excel workbook, using a suitable link format so you can span page breaks.